# How to get websocket data into an observable and display with ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, observable, ngfor

I'm getting data from binance websocket and trying to display its properties on a table using ngfor but getting "Cannot read property 'dispose of null' " error on the console. What do i need to change?

I've tried to get only one row of data without using ngfor and it was successful. But i need to get more than one value on the table.

Here's my socket service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io-client';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;

  public connect(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if (!this.subject) {
      this.subject = this.create(url);
      console.log('Successfully connected: ' + url);
    }
    return this.subject;
  }

  private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(url);

    let observable = Rx.Observable.create((obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
      ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
      ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
      ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
      return ws.close.bind(ws);
    });
    let observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      }
    };
    return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }
}
```

Here's my message service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { SocketService } from './socket.service';

const CHAT_URL = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethbtc@ticker';

export interface Message {
  sym: string;
  prch: string;
  prchp: string;
  lastp: string;


}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class MsgService {
  public messages: Subject<Message>;

constructor(wsService: SocketService) {  this.messages = wsService.connect(CHAT_URL).map(
  (response: MessageEvent): Message => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    return {
      sym: data.s,
      lastp: data.c,
      prch: data.p,
      prchp: data.P
    };
    }
) as Subject<Message>;

}
sendMsg(msg) {
  this.messages.next(msg);
}

}
```

Here's my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MsgService, Message } from '../msg.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  public values: Message;

  constructor(private apiservice: ApiService,private router: Router,private msgService: MsgService) { }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.msgService.messages.subscribe(data => this.values = data);

  }

onSelect(value){
this.router.navigate(['/detailed', value.symbol]);
}

}
```

And it's html

```
<div class="container">


<h1 style="margin-left: 40%">
  Currencies
</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-info ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Last Price</th>
      <th>24h Volume</th>
      <th>24h Pct Change</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr (click)="onSelect(value)" *ngFor="let value of values | async">
      <td><a [routerLink]="['/detailed']"> {{value.sym}} </a></td>
      <td>{{value.prch}}</td>
      <td>{{value.prchp}}</td>
      <td>{{value.lastp}}</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

I expect getting the html table filled with data coming from websocket. Instead I'm getting this on console:

```
 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null
    at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe._dispose (common.js:4937)
    at AsyncPipe.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.AsyncPipe.transform (common.js:4912)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (MainComponent.html:19)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23307)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23511)
```

Comment: Would you like to try to bind `public values : Message` to your components template via `{{  values | json }}` and tell me how your values is being received by your component..

Would you also please remove the `| async` pipe in your template as `public values: Message` is not an **Observable** but a normal _Object_

Comment: When i remove async, console returns an error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."   Binding {{values | json }} just returned this one =  {}

Comment: well that is good, now we know that our `values: Message` needs to be an array. The next debugging part would be to check the spot where you set `values: Message`.. Because as it looks right now, your `values: Message` is not being populated in your component.. otherwise binding `{{ values | json }}` would not be `{}` (empty object **NOT** undefined).. add here a logging `this.msgService.messages.subscribe(data => { console.log(data); this.values = data});` then we can check if your component receives the data we are expecting

Comment: Okay when I get the log it returns as you said. {sym: undefined, lastp: undefined, prch: undefined, prchp: undefined}. Why are they undefined?

Comment: ok I am bit confused .. could you please output your `private create(url)` function by subscribing to it in the SocketService and not from outside.. And could you also please verify that your successfull connection to the socket is being outputted

Comment: I can successfully connect to the socket because i can see console writes "Successfully connected: wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!ticker@arr"  . How should i subscribe to private create(url)  ?

Comment: I could not fully understand why you are returning an observable in the function if you want to set it for the **subject** property anyway.. therefore please try this one to subscribe to it: `this.subject = this.create(url);` change to `this.create(url);` - Then instead of `return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);` do `this.subject = Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);`.. now subsribe to it in your constructor: `constructor() {this.subject.subscribe(log => console.log(\`subscribed\`,log))}`, hopefully we shall see something now :)

Comment: aah now I see what you were doing, you do not make your subject public.. therefore it will not works as I described it.. I am using the redux pattern therefore, my data fly is one-way and not like yours two-way.. I would suggest you to make your private subscribe property public and your connect() function to a void function.. you run the code to connect and subscribe to your public subscribe Property of the service.. you have more control and it is cleaner that way

Comment: Unfortunately app has crashed due to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined"

Comment: ok use it then as it was before but can you please make sure that `create(url)` actually returns the subscription which ouptuts the expected data?

Comment: Yes it returns some other data if change the url to get only one piece of data

Comment: can you show me which data you get in your MsgService constructor().. it could be that you need also to subscribe to your Subject there in order to get the data

Comment: It gets a data like this: {
  "e": "24hrTicker",  // Event type
  "E": 123456789,     // Event time
  "s": "BNBBTC",      // Symbol
  "p": "0.0015",      // Price change
  "P": "250.00",      // Price change percent
  "w": "0.0018",      // Weighted average price

Comment: ok, can you show me your constructor of MsgService as you have it now? Because this is the only spot left where the data flow is interrupted. public messages does not emit the data to the component

Comment: Here's my constructor of MsgService `constructor(wsService: SocketService) {  this.messages = wsService.connect(CHAT_URL).map(
  (response: MessageEvent): Message => {
    const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
    return {
      sym: data.s,
      lastp: data.c,
      prch: data.p,
      prchp: data.P
    };
    }
) as Subject<Message>;

}`

Comment: ok, you are not updating your messages property in the whole process. Just replace your logging with `this.messages.next(data)`

Comment: sorry but i didn't get it where do i need to replace it ?